# Objects in Swift: Value of 'Object' has no member

Tags: swift, swift2, realm

Here's my doozy.

I've got this lovely little function in a file called functions.swift

```
//functions.swift

     func latestActiveGoal() -> Object {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            let currentGoal = realm.objects(Goal).filter("Active == 1").sorted("CreatedOn").last
            return currentGoal!
        }
```

which returns a `Goal` object. (A Goal might be wanting to lose weight, or stop being so inept at Swift).

In a different view controller, I want to access this object. Here's what I'm trying:

```
//viewController.swift

@IBOutlet weak var aimText: UILabel!

let funky = functions()

    func getGoals(){

            var currentGoal = funky.latestActiveGoal()
            print(currentGoal)

            aimText.text = currentGoal.Title
    }
```

The `print(CurrentGoal)` output shows this:

```
Goal {
    id = 276;
    Title = Goal Title;
    Aim = Aim;
    Action = Nothing;
    Active = 1;
    CreatedOn = 2016-02-12 00:14:45 +0000;
}
```

`aimText.text = currentGoal.Title` and `aimText = currentGoal.Title` both throw the error:

`Value of 'Object' has no member 'Title'`

By printing the contents of the object, I can see the data, but can't figure out how. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: show full error message please.

Comment: @BryanChen updated my question with error messages, as suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message said, `currentGoal` is a value of `Object` type which doesn't have member `Title`.

This is because function `latestActiveGoal` returns `Object` instead of `Goal`. You just need to make it return `Goal` by change the return type:

```
func latestActiveGoal() -> Goal {
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just replace your functions with below code.
It will works perfect.**

This fuction will check if goal available, then only it will return.

```
func latestActiveGoal() -> Object? {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            let currentGoals = realm.objects(Goal).filter("Active == 1").sorted("CreatedOn")
            if currentGoals.count > 0 {
                 return currentGoals.last;
            }
            return nil;
        }
```

Your `getGoals` method will be as follow.

```
func getGoals(){    
    if let currentGoalObject = funky.latestActiveGoal() {
        print(currentGoalObject)
        let goal = currentGoalObject as! Goal
        print(goal.Title)
        aimText.text = goal.Title
    }
}
```